# How to send, store and analyze sensor data using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

My Raspberry pi 2 is doing good with windows 10 and I'm able to control LED from internet using .Net MF. Now, I wanted to send my LED (I'm going to use temperature sensor instead of LED) ON-OFF signal onto big data for storing and analyzing or retrieving purpose.

Checked on net, not able to find the simple and easy way to do that. Could any one please suggest any tutorial for "How can I send real time data to Hadoop"? I want to understand whole architecture to proceed on this.
What all technologies/things I should concentrate on to make such POC?

Note: I think, I need some combination like MQTT broker, Spark or Strom etc...But not sure, how can I put all things together to make it practically possible. Please correct me if I'm wrong and help.

Answer (score 1):

You could send the signals as a stream of events to Hadoop in real time, using one of several components which make up the Hadoop "ecosystem". Systems such as Spark or Storm which are for processing the data in real time are only necessary if you want to apply logic to the stream in real-time. If you just want to batch up the events and store them in HDFS for later retrieval by a batch process, you could use:

- **Apache Flume**. A Flume agent runs on one or more of the Hadoop nodes and listens on a port. Your Raspberry Pi sends each event one by one to that port. Flume buffers the events and then writes them to HDFS https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html
- **Kafka**. Your Raspberry Pi sends the events one by one to a Kafka instance which stores them as a message queue. A further distributed batch process runs periodically on Hadoop in order to move the events from Kafka to HDFS. This solution is more robust but has more moving parts.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Really helpful. I'll try and share my knowledge. Could you please include few links in your answer for this(Flume/Kafka + Raspberry Pi + Windows 10 IoT core)? I mean, kind of end to end tutorial with few sample code. Moreover, how MQTT broker plays a role in this? Could you please explain something about role of MQTT broker ? Thanks again.